# Laravel ) How to register a schedule from the controller

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to receive a GET Request in HelloController and execute a scheduled process (HelloWorldCommand) based on the content of request, but I am having trouble understanding how to do this.

PHP 8.2.7
Laravel Framework 10.25.0

In the following situation, GET request works and no error is output, but scheduling is not performed. What should I do?

HelloController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use App\Console\Commands\HelloWorldCommand;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    //
  public function index()
  {
    $output = '';
    $variableValue = 'SampleValue';
    Artisan::call('command:hello', ['variable' => $variableValue, '--quiet'=>true], $output);

    var_dump($output);

    return view('hello');
  }
}
```

HelloWorldCommand.php

```
class HelloWorldCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:hello {variable}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $v = $this->argument('variable');
        //

        $schedule = app(Schedule::class);
        $schedule->call(function () {
             logger("log {$v}");
        })->everyMinute();

        logger('test');

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expected it to be written to the log file every minute, but the implementation was not processed on a scheduled basis.

Comment: it's not really a "scheduled" process, if you want to trigger it irregularly from your controller. that's not how scheduling works.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem of why it doesn't work, is a mix of the fact that your crontab running the scheduler, will never be aware of your request context specific addition of a schedule and that your addition is only temporary, as the processed lines in `HelloWorldCommand::handle()` only exists till your request has finished.

So basically, what you're trying to do isn't possible.

You should probably look into queuing jobs instead, which is something you could do to achieve a similar implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The schedule could not be called from controller its called from **App\Console\Kernel.php** file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use App\Console\Commands\HelloWorldCommand;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('Your Command')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function to perform the job you want and call it recursively in you controller.

```
function schedule($input,$delay_time = 60 ){
// Whatever you want to do with $input here.
sleep($delay_time);
schedule($delay_time);
}

schedule($_GET['request']);
```

This function will run each 60 second. Hope i have got what you want. English is my second language.